# Do the Expresso Store shipping methods have to be displayed in a dropdown?

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

Is it possible, in Expresso Store, to display the shipping methods not in a dropdown, but in radial buttons or tick boxes instead? I'd like to display shipping methods side by side in designed boxes with radial buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shipping method is a standard input field, you can template it however you want:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="3" />
```

Or, if you want to automatically generate the list:

```
{shipping_methods}
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="shipping_method" value="{method_id}" />
        {method_title}
    </label>
{/shipping_methods}
```

Documentation here: https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#shipping_methods