# Shipping Rates in {shipping_method} Dropdown - Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store, extension, shipping

Is it possible to show the shipping rate next to the shipping option in the {shipping_method} dropdown? I'm using the Store USPS Shipping Extension to calculate shipping costs.

I would like to show something like this in the dropdown:

- First-Class Mail Parcel ($3.04)
- Priority Mail 2-Day ($7.15)
- Priority Mail Express 1-Day ($31.20)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here in case it helps anyone else.

This question/answer pointed me in the right direction:
[Do the Expresso Store shipping methods have to be displayed in a dropdown?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/10956/do-the-expresso-store-shipping-methods-have-to-be-displayed-in-a-dropdown)

The solution was to use the {shipping_methods} variable pair:

```
<select name="shipping_method">
    <option value="">Select a shipping method...</option>
    {shipping_methods}
    <option value="{method_id}">{method_title} ({method_price})</option>
    {/shipping_methods}
</select>
```

I can confirm that this works with the Store USPS Shipping Extension (v1.1.0), contrary to the Expresso Store docs.